# Automatically "copy" rows from another spreadsheet page depending on the value of a column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a document of backlog, and I have a page called "Ideas". In that page we set the priority of the ideas and in which sprint is going to be done.

I want to automatically copy the tasks to another pages depending on the sprint name, which it will the same name as in the other page.

For example. In my document in the page "ideas":

```
P   Description         Due
1   Amazing logo        V0
1   Legal Texts         V0
1   Customer.io Webhock V1
```

And I want that in the page V0, the first 2 rows were copied to that page.

Page V0:

```
 1  Amazing logo        V0
 1  Legal Texts         V0
```

Page V1:

```
1   Customer.io Webhock V1
```

Comment: not sure if this can be done as a formula without a bunch of spaces and/or filtering.  you may want to add a Excel-VBA tag

Comment: In case of a google spreadsheet, a simple query can solve this. E.g in sheet V0, cell A1 enter: =query(Ideas!A1:C, "where C = 'V0' ", 1) where A1:C is the range that holds the data from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT` I am having a hard time understanding exactly what you are wanting but it would look something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C100="V0")*1, B1:B100)
```

This will look for V0 in column C and then return the value of the corresponding row in column B. SUMPRODUCT is very useful. You can also use multiple search criteria by changing the 1 to another range such as

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C100="V0")*(A1:A100=1), B1:B100)
```

so it will look for V0 in C and 1 in A and return what is in B if both match.